# Wordpress, jQuery function scope

Tags: jquery, wordpress

This issue is driving me crazy. I think this problem is concerned with variable/function scope, which I obviously don't really understand well.

I'm working in WordPress (although that probably doesn't matter because I think this is a problem just with my jQuery).

I've set up 2 functions and also 2 variables which are defined outside those functions so, from tutorials I've read, this means the variables are global and can be accessed from anywhere in the script (???)

So, the first function (gallery a - click function) sets some values for the 2 variables (an `<img>` tag src attribute and text for a description of image. This works fine.

However, calling function 2 (btn-2) should clear the values previously set by function 1. This doesn't work. I set up a very simple test outside of WordPress and got it to work but the script won't work in WordPress.

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong??

The code snippet below shows the relevant part of the jQuery script I'm using. The jQuery script is loaded into WordPress by enqueuing and, apart from this issue, seems to be working fine.

```
var imgsrc;
var description;

// Function 1

$('#gallery a').click(function(){

    if ($(this).data("attachment-id") === 123) {

        range = "Coloured Concrete";

        imgsrc = "images/some-image.jpg"; 
        $('.target_image').attr("src", imgsrc);

        description = "Some description";
        $('.description').html(description);

    }

});

//Function 2

$('#btn-2').click(function(){

    imgsrc = "images/blank.jpg"; 
    $('.target_image').attr("src", imgsrc);

    description = " ";
    $('.description').html(description);

});
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Which of the two functions is losing the scope?

Comment: Are you saying `$('.target_image').attr("src", imgsrc);` from function 2 src is set to `"images/some-image.jpg"` and not  `"images/blank.jpg"; `

Comment: Yes. When btn-2 is clicked, $('.target_image').attr("src", imgsrc); is still set to images/some-images.jpg. It doesn't change to images/blank.jpg as required. Also, description does not change from "Some description" to " " (blank).

Comment: Can you verify that the btn-2 click function is even running? Try adding this first line to the btn-2 function: ` alert('function firing!');

Comment: @Greg Burkett Yes, it runs

Comment: So, does it work if you completely bypass the variable and instead just do: `$('.target_image').attr("src", "images/blank.jpg");`